# tikzposter and tikz[remember picture, overlay] conflict

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing because I'm not very experienced in `TikZ` and I'm not able to make it work in conjunction with the package `tikzposter`.

I'm trying to get manual positioning of images in the title region and I thought of implementing that using a `tikzfigure` with `remember picture` and `overlay` options.

However this results in the whole page being moved: the center of the document ends up in the top left corner of the page (I had to use Inkscape to see this, as pdf readers will only show what's drawn inside page margins).

This is a MWE of the code I'm using to reproduce this issue:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex

\documentclass{tikzposter}

\begin{document}
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{}
\end{document}
```

The error persists if I provide all the fields and insert a `\maketitle` before or after the tikz picture.

I'm using the latest version of the `tikzposter` package, downloaded from the bitbucket repository, and the version of `tikz` provided by texlive in Debian Sid repositories (2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151))

Cheers,

P.S: Problem is found compiling with both pdflatex and lualatex.

P.S2: Pictures
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this minimal example gives an error?

Comment: Indeed, if needed I could provide screenshots (both from Evince and Inkscape).

Comment: You can add `\listfiles` to your document and check the log for `tikz.sty` (current version of TikZ is 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151). This document produces no error for me. (TL 2017) using `tikzposter` 2014/01/15 v2.0.

Comment: I'm using tikzposter v2.1 (from bitbucket), because this version solved an error in \printbibliography. Seems that I'm now stuck between two broken versions one day before handout :-)

Comment: I have misunderstood the problem, sorry. I get the same issue you are reporting.  Perhaps instead you can show an example of what you want to achieve with overlays and it can be done a different way?

Comment: No problem, it's hard to read, better to look. I've uploaded images ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page of a tikzposter is already a tikz picture. So if you want to put things in it use tikz commands directly:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\node at(TP@title.south) {\includegraphics{example-image-A}};
\draw[red,line width=1cm](0,0)--++(-10,-10); 
\end{document}
```

[image]